# Extending social-auth-app-django with a custom User model

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I am using Django v2 and social-auth-app-django.

I have successfully made the user authenticate using Google+, and it updates my Users table under Authentication and Authorization with a firstname, lastname, email, username and staff status.

I want to extend the current model so that it can take in more fields. Something like creating a profile after logging in for the first time.

I do understand there are similar questions here, but none of them has complete answers. I am not asking for a full solution, but if someone can point me in the right direction, it'd be great. I am just starting with Django, and the docs can be a bit complex.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I think this link will help: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: Hello, thanks for the resource. I should ideally be a using a one to one link right?

Comment: Yes, follow that tutorial and it should show you.